# How to add command button inside user form in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a command button (inside my UserForm) from the toolbox but I don't have it in my controls neither in the additional controls! 
What should I do?
I added a pictures for you to see my [ToolBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umDNc.png).
I have to mention that I have windows 10 excel
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this control as below image

[image]